# How to handle if any json files are failed to load in react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am keeping JSON files in the public folder and using xhr-backend to load them. And kept

```
react: {
            useSuspense: true,
            wait: true
         }
```

so that page will be displayed after all strings are loaded. However in very rare cases 1 or 2 users facing the problem that they can see keys instead of the actual text. (After reloading actual text appeared)

So

1. How could I know in which cases it is happening
2. Even though in the worst case if JSON files are not loaded is there any standard approach to handle those failure cases?

Answer (score -1):

simply you can use `try catch` block

```js
try {
  /* handle json here */
} catch(error) {
  /* handle error case here */
}
```